# Google Analytics offline and Queue Time

Tags: google-analytics

We're hoping to use Google Analytics for a product that will only be connected to the internet maybe once a week so we're trying to sort out how long Google Analytics works offline. We came across this in the documentation:

*Queue Time
Optional.
Used to collect offline / latent hits. The value represents the time delta (in milliseconds) between when the hit being reported occurred and the time the hit was sent. The value must be greater than or equal to 0. Values greater than four hours may lead to hits not being processed.*

I've seen some posts on here mention that it can work passed 4 hours, but overall does this mean Google Analytics isn't reliable passed 4 hours offline?